# Java SSLHandshakeException "no cipher suites in common"

Tags: java, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

I'm using an SSLServerSocket to accept client connections on my openSUSE server, but none of them can connect. I always get an SSLHandshakeException saying `no cipher suites in common`. I've activated all of the possible suites, enabled multiple protocols, tried with the newest oracle JRE and the openjdk. Also I followed several other posts on forums and stuff and "unlocked" all the cipher suites in the jre of oracle and I changed the settings of the openjdk jre like this:

disabled: `#security.provider.10=sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 ${java.home}/lib/security/nss.cfg`
and enabled: `security.provider.9=sun.security.ec.SunEC`

This is how I initialize my SSLServerSocket:

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "./keystore");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "nopassword");
    java.lang.System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");

// Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }

                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
            }
    };

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
    SSLServerSocket ssl = (SSLServerSocket) sc.getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(
            DownloadFilelist.PORT);
    // Got rid of:
    //ssl.setEnabledCipherSuites(sc.getServerSocketFactory().getSupportedCipherSuites());
    ssl.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2", "SSLv3"});

    // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ssl.getEnabledCipherSuites()));

    s = ssl;
    // s = new ServerSocket(DownloadFilelist.PORT);
    s.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT);
```

The Problem is that I can't find out what cipher suites the clients want neither can I influence it. I started the program with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake`, [here](http://pastebin.com/ypj1Wf5C) is the result. Can someone of you figure out what the problem is?

**EDIT** The keystore was generated with: `keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keystore ./keystore`

Here's the code on this page, if that helps (seems like the formatting is not messed up):

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
main, setSoTimeout(2000) called
Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1361763651 bytes = { 159, 113, 250, 254, 103, 37, 66, 234, 127, 4, 36, 240, 60, 252, 55, 112, 6, 224, 192, 181, 146, 163, 63, 148, 152, 255, 77, 8 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 67
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 81
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1361763767 bytes = { 249, 20, 120, 68, 76, 110, 168, 235, 47, 91, 119, 64, 151, 242, 169, 191, 111, 105, 146, 90, 173, 223, 55, 127, 133, 12, 1, 247 }
Session ID:  {246, 66, 250, 209, 13, 188, 190, 246, 14, 49, 113, 183, 192, 202, 68, 246, 121, 162, 165, 71, 242, 220, 233, 223, 245, 47, 250, 215, 203, 94, 255, 148}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 933
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=dc.hadiko.de, O=hadiko dc, L=town, ST=land of the free, C=de
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 22613010171436639614880560956464961031555258188367451246658444583390999370970098210909007150132692078653881042731046316239498513359691936582885343174669796075601988313858262934995935649363223919652108615287224220030023261629874169998331654587246748976585212101810697310529416436829153514374554242128947092694064999520197281527578067183301918060451970607703466399571245107774569719996572643148013190800713656468629158991997127544540177983174906099325217344868710319256330960086862269228933938482311029685238274537823670267001618579382801319470736924423550865055775144486750164961588873175599114046362924859400297960451
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Sat Jul 07 12:56:23 CEST 2012,
               To: Tue Jul 07 12:56:23 CEST 2015]
  Issuer: CN=dc.hadiko.de, O=hadiko dc, L=town, ST=land of the free, C=de
  SerialNumber: [    8682354f f94fbbb5]

Certificate Extensions: 3
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 43 1D D9 A7 CF 21 2E 17   F3 4E EE F6 6C 6C 88 16  C....!...N..ll..
0010: 08 3C 67 8E                                        .<g.
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 43 1D D9 A7 CF 21 2E 17   F3 4E EE F6 6C 6C 88 16  C....!...N..ll..
0010: 08 3C 67 8E                                        .<g.
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 14 83 48 D3 EC 39 49 E3   9C BC 20 F5 BF E4 32 33  ..H..9I... ...23
0010: 5F 09 8F 2D F2 C3 82 80   79 93 9A C1 97 93 92 D9  _..-....y.......
0020: D0 DA 4D B2 FC A1 43 60   1F B9 EA 4C 29 D7 79 D0  ..M...C`...L).y.
0030: 66 8C 25 14 EB 9D 60 94   D7 F4 15 33 8B 17 24 24  f.%...`....3..$$
0040: 5C 65 26 3D C3 B0 8A 51   B6 27 01 D1 A6 A3 68 87  \e&=...Q.'....h.
0050: 2D 6F 0B E6 00 96 B6 CF   BC E9 D2 9C 7E 19 9E E1  -o..............
0060: 3A 96 42 2E B7 E8 C0 70   01 99 20 39 89 6D 94 2B  :.B....p.. 9.m.+
0070: 76 2F F1 0E 6D 2D 9B 52   77 D3 63 6A 11 DC A3 E6  v/..m-.Rw.cj....
0080: 4E 0E 64 6D FA 77 BC 1E   4F C3 91 AD 21 F7 5D 31  N.dm.w..O...!.]1
0090: F9 04 A5 FA 34 EF 43 61   F1 42 32 5A 9B D1 16 84  ....4.Ca.B2Z....
00A0: 07 2B CA 01 AF 84 54 D2   A9 C4 3A 7A EA D1 2A 95  .+....T...:z..*.
00B0: 47 30 03 BA 48 C4 57 1F   78 58 6C 7A 56 60 40 2C  G0..H.W.xXlzV`@,
00C0: 6A 17 15 3F 43 A5 FB 81   4D 9D 1B DC A7 CE 78 D1  j..?C...M.....x.
00D0: 5A 66 97 79 04 55 DA 34   3C B2 CD 9A 62 EE 32 22  Zf.y.U.4<...b.2"
00E0: 70 84 0E 3E 5D 7F 91 0D   A5 D4 84 6B F3 E9 40 E9  p..>]......k..@.
00F0: E8 69 D7 E5 FC B6 0A 4C   35 66 CC BA E5 38 12 A0  .i.....L5f...8..

]
***
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 4
*** ServerHelloDone
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 262
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 03 01 59 D3 0F F9 95 E8   DC E2 C2 4A 2B 93 79 55  ..Y........J+.yU
0010: 0B 1A 43 5E F4 0A 73 F1   13 E1 00 DF 78 55 F6 52  ..C^..s.....xU.R
0020: 4E 6A D3 2C F8 08 A1 B3   03 DF C9 5E 8C 14 8D 4E  Nj.,.......^...N
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 51 2B DD 43 9F 71 FA FE   67 25 42 EA 7F 04 24 F0  Q+.C.q..g%B...$.
0010: 3C FC 37 70 06 E0 C0 B5   92 A3 3F 94 98 FF 4D 08  <.7p......?...M.
Server Nonce:
0000: 51 2B DE B7 F9 14 78 44   4C 6E A8 EB 2F 5B 77 40  Q+....xDLn../[w@
0010: 97 F2 A9 BF 6F 69 92 5A   AD DF 37 7F 85 0C 01 F7  ....oi.Z..7.....
Master Secret:
0000: 3E 9E 24 42 3D E4 82 AF   AD 97 76 EF 06 EF FB FD  >.$B=.....v.....
0010: C8 1A D5 7E 8E A2 74 4D   E8 E7 B9 1E 60 E9 E0 6F  ......tM....`..o
0020: 09 E3 56 81 FC 2D 20 D9   69 6B 26 C3 0B C5 53 5F  ..V..- .ik&...S_
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: 04 30 70 7E A9 4A 1F 88   55 F8 31 31 75 36 40 35  .0p..J..U.11u6@5
0010: 25 65 24 5D                                        %e$]
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: 8B C1 65 50 6D 11 21 32   CD 50 3A AB 0F 2E A5 FC  ..ePm.!2.P:.....
0010: C7 30 E6 EC                                        .0..
Client write key:
0000: 25 D7 96 B0 9A 1F 49 95   06 4D 05 36 2E D0 38 04  %.....I..M.6..8.
0010: 0F 32 15 2E 8F 0A 6C 79   F8 ED E8 9B FE 5C 2C D8  .2....ly.....\,.
Server write key:
0000: 4A 91 5D DF B2 FE 6F 35   3E 8A 21 DF 17 E0 35 F0  J.]...o5>.!...5.
0010: DB 97 4C 7E 18 07 7E 27   DD AD BC C4 C4 28 C5 E1  ..L....'.....(..
Client write IV:
0000: B6 C1 98 05 9B 37 F9 0F   4E 0C 0F 6E 08 8A 26 C9  .....7..N..n..&.
Server write IV:
0000: 0E 83 27 3E 3B 40 E8 BE   4C 58 C4 5F EF E4 D3 4C  ..'>;@..LX._...L
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 23, 181, 134, 191, 68, 30, 119, 81, 239, 135, 238, 80 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
main, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 254, 182, 228, 50, 121, 214, 35, 175, 100, 128, 102, 152 }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 48
HSent: HSUP ADBASE ADTIGR ADBLOM
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 32
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 48
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 32
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 32
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 32
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 288
ClientManager, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 32
ClientManager, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 96

[...] (Cut out becauseI exceeded body limit.)

ClientManager, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 80
ClientManager, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 32
ClientManager, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 80
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 32
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 64
Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
A client, READ: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 112
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1361763651 bytes = { 47, 7, 95, 146, 25, 28, 95, 191, 146, 159, 184, 47, 149, 220, 67, 169, 121, 123, 252, 98, 0, 253, 108, 88, 108, 188, 52, 76 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: Unknown (hash:0x4, signature:0x2), SHA256withRSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-2, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
A client, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
A client, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
A client, called closeSocket()
A client, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

The output contains one connect to another server that works and then the connection to my server. I can't remove the other connect, because I'm getting the information on how to connect over this connection. I could enable debugging after the first connect, if that's possible, but I don't know how...

I removed all not related output (Output that I created).

**UPDATE:**

I can't even connect to myself. When I create a SSLServerSocket and an SSLSocket to connect to it in the same application, I get the same error. But when I compare the lists of enabled cipher suites, There are a bunch of suites that are supported by both sockets. I've tested that on Windows 7 64bit with the newest JDK.

**UPDATE:**

I just started the server part of my program from scratch using a tutorial, and magically it worked... I have no idea why, but it seems like I should have just used as much standard implementations as possible. I give the reputation to Bruno, since he put the most effort in his post.

Comment: It looks like there are multiple connections in your SSL trace, possibly from other threads.

Comment: Jep, exactly two, as I've written below it.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You're initialising your `SSLContext` with a `null` `KeyManager` array.

The key manager is what handles the server certificate (on the server side), and this is what you're probably aiming to set when using `javax.net.ssl.keyStore`.

However, as described in the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLContext), using `null` for the first parameter doesn't do what you seem to think it does:

> If the KeyManager[] parameter is null, then an empty KeyManager will
>   be defined for this context. If the TrustManager[] parameter is null,
>   the installed security providers will be searched for the
>   highest-priority implementation of the TrustManagerFactory, from which
>   an appropriate TrustManager will be obtained. Likewise, the
>   SecureRandom parameter may be null, in which case a default
>   implementation will be used.

An empty `KeyManager` doesn't contain any RSA or DSA certificates. Therefore, all the default cipher suites that would rely on such a certificate are disabled. This is why you get all these "*Ignoring unavailable cipher suite*" messages, which ultimately result in a "*no cipher suites in common*" message.

If you want your keystore to be used as a keystore, you'll need to load it and initialise a KeyManagerFactory with it:

```
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    InputStream ksIs = new FileInputStream("...");
    try {
        ks.load(ksIs, "password".toCharArray());
    } finally {
        if (ksIs != null) {
            ksIs.close();
        }
    }

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory
            .getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(ks, "keypassword".toCharArray());
```

The use `kmf.getKeyManagers()` as the first parameter to `SSLContext.init()`.

For the other two parameters, since you're visibly not requesting client-certificate authentication, you should leave the trust manager to its default value (`null`) instead of copying/pasting a trust manager that's a potential cause of vulnerability, and you can also use the default `null` `SecureRandom`.

Comment: Very good answer. I'd like to add one thing: I got the same error even though the KeyManager was correctly selected by Jetty. The problem, in my case was thet my JKS file, which I created from a PEM certificate chain, did not contain the private key entry - I forgot to add the private key entry and the error was the same. Once I rebuilt my JKS file to include the private key too it all started working. You can still see the 'Ignoring unavailable cipher suite' messages but the handshake is performed and the 'no cipher suites in common' errors are not encountered anymore. Hope this helps.

Comment: Are "keypassword" and "password" supposed to be different? I tried using my keystore and in my case they both were the same.

Comment: @RestInPeace It depends on how that keystore was set up. They can be the same (and often are), but they can also be different (depending on the type of keystore).

Answer (score 23):

Having had this exception myself, I delved into the JRE source code. It became apparent that the message is rather misleading. It *could* mean what it says, but it more generally means that the server doesn't have the data it needs to respond to the client in the requested way. This can happen, for example, if certificates are missing from the keystore, or haven't been generated with the an appropriate algoritm. Indeed, given the cipher suites that are installed by default, one would have to go to some lengths to really get this exception because of lack of common cipher suites. In my particular case I'd generated the certificates with the default algorithm of DSA, when what I needed to get the server to work with Firefox was RSA.

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy Yes it does.

Comment: Had exactly this due to keystore alias not matching the server configured alias. Infuriatingly misleading error message. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: A prime example of this cause is the server not having a private key at all. That means it can only use use anonymous cipher suites, and if the client didn't send any, there are literally no cipher suites in common.

Comment: The message is indeed misleading, to say the least.  This saved my bacon by giving me a hint where to look.  Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

This problem can be caused by undue manipulation of the enabled cipher suites at the client or the server, but I suspect the most common cause is the server not having a private key and certificate at all.

NB:

```
ssl.setEnabledCipherSuites(sc.getServerSocketFactory().getSupportedCipherSuites());
```

Get rid of this line. Your server is insecure enough already with that insecure `TrustManager`. Then run your server with `-Djavax.net.debug=SSL,handshake,` try one connect, and post the resulting output here.

Comment: Do you mean here like here or a Link? Because the whole formatting is completely messed up on this page...

Comment: Here's the link: http://pastebin.com/Xpt8Cm3X The output contains one connect to another server that works and then the connection to my server. I can't remove the other connect, because I'm getting the information on how to connect over this connection. I could enable debugging after the first connect, if that's possible, but I don't know how...

Comment: @Sibbo I don't know what 'like here or a Link' means, or what's unclear about this answer. The output you've provided a link to only proves that you haven't taken this advice yet.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I got this `no cipher suites in common` error because I've loaded a `p12` format file to the keystore of the server, instead of a `jks` file.

Answer (score 4):

For debugging when I start java add like mentioned:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```

then you can see that the browser tried to use TLSv1 and Jetty 9.1.3 was talking TLSv1.2
so they were not communicating. That's Firefox. Chrome wanted SSLv3 so I added that also.

```
sslContextFactory.setIncludeProtocols( "TLSv1", "SSLv3" );  <-- Fix
sslContextFactory.setRenegotiationAllowed(true);   <-- added don't know if helps anything.
```

I did not do most of the other stuff the orig poster did:

```
// Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
```

or this answer:

```
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory
        .getDefaultAlgorithm());
```

or

```
.setEnabledCipherSuites
```

---

I created one self signed cert like this: (but I added .jks to filename)
and read that in my jetty java code.
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html

```
keytool -keystore keystore.jks -alias jetty -genkey -keyalg RSA
```

first & lastname   *.mywebdomain.com

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to connect using TLSv1.2, which isn't widely implemented on servers. Does your destination support tls1.2?

Comment: From the source code of the connecting software (eiskaltdcpp) I know, that it probably supports TLSv1.1 (If I read it correct). If I also have TLSv1.1 in this list, doesn't that mean that both protocols are possible and it depends on the client which is chosen? But I will definetly test it and edit this comment.

Comment: That didn't change anything.

Comment: Actually, tls1.1 is not too widely supported either. What type of ssl server are you connecting to? I'm thinking of this line: `SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");`. Maybe that was the line you were editing (and I could be wrong) but that line is opening up the connection using TLS1.2.

Comment: I can connect to any server, but the SSLServerSocket does not work. I can't even connect to the same application while using all defaults and just TLSv1. I think I will try to reinstall Java tomorrow, but it's strange that the test program I used (something from the internet using all defaults) neither worked on my PC nor on the openSUSE server...

Answer (score 1):

I got this error with this ... unfortunate... package I have to use and I don't have source for.  After much digging (thank you, Stack Overflow) and trying endless combinations, I finally got things running by:

1. Creating the [JKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_KeyStore) with the entire certificate chain.
2. Making sure the key in the JKS had the alias of the [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) of the machine.
3. Renaming the alias of the certificate for my machine ${FQDN}.cert

This took endless experimentation with the java command line options:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose:keymanager:trustmanager 
-Djava.security.debug=access:stack
```

My key and [CSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) were produced in OpenSSL so I had to import the key with:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in  cert.pem -inkey  cert.key -CAfile fullChain.pem -name ${FQDN} -out cert.p12
keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore cert.jks -srckeystore cert.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12
```

keytool complains about the format so I converted the format followed by adding my cert chain:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore cert.jks -destkeystore cert_p12.jks -deststoretype pkcs12
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias 'DigiCert Global Root G2 IntermediateCA' -keystore cert_p12.jks -file cert2.pem -storepass "$STOREPASS" -keypass "$KEYPASS" 
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias 'DigiCert Global Root G2'                -keystore cert_p12.jks -file cert3.pem -storepass "$STOREPASS" -keypass "$KEYPASS"
```

(where cert2.pem and cert3.pem were downloaded from the DigiCert web site and converted to PEM format.)
When I restarted the application with the resulting `jks` file, things started to work.

Something else I figured out as part of this.  You can check the certificate chain by using:

```
openssl x509 -in cert2.pem -noout -text
```

for all your certificates and studying the output, paying attention to the `X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:` and `X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:` lines.  The `X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:` of one level matches the `X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:` of the next higher level.  You found the top of chain when the `Issuer:` string matches the `Subject:` string.

I hope this can save somebody some of the time it took me.

Answer (score -2):

Server

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import javax.net.*;
class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
      SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
      context.init(null,null,null);
      SSLServerSocketFactory serverSocketFactory = context.getServerSocketFactory();
      SSLServerSocket server = (SSLServerSocket)serverSocketFactory.createServerSocket(1024);
      server.setEnabledCipherSuites(server.getSupportedCipherSuites());
      SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)server.accept();
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      System.out.println(in.readInt());
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
  }
}
```

Client

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import javax.net.*;
class Test2{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
      SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
      context.init(null,null,null);
      SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
      SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)socketFactory.createSocket("localhost", 1024);
      socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(socket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      out.writeInt(1337);     
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
  }
}
```

server.setEnabledCipherSuites(server.getSupportedCipherSuites());
socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(socket.getSupportedCipherSuites());

Comment: Insecure. This enables all the anonymous cipher suites. Don't do this.