# Grizzly 2 Embedded Https Server?

Tags: java, https, grizzly

I'm trying to get a simple https embedded server running. This is for a test prototype, so real security isn't important at this point and fake or omitted certificates are fine, but my situation requires https vs regular http.

This code seems to call the right APIs, it runs, but the client browser gets "SSL Connection Error":

```
public class SimpleHttps {
    public static final String SERVER_NAME = "https://localhost:8090";
    public static final URI BASE_URI = URI.create(SERVER_NAME);

    private static class TrustAllCerts implements X509TrustManager {
        @Override public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException { }
        @Override public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException { }
        @Override public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return new X509Certificate[0]; }
    }

    private final static TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new TrustAllCerts() };

    public static SSLEngineConfigurator getSslEngineConfig() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        SSLEngineConfigurator sslEngineConfigurator = new SSLEngineConfigurator(sc, false, false, false);
        return sslEngineConfigurator;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().register(MyResource.class);
        HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc, true, getSslEngineConfig());

        System.in.read();

        httpServer.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to enable ssl debug info on the server side?

Comment: -Djavax.net.debug=all

Comment: See this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076820/java-sslhandshakeexception-no-cipher-suites-in-common