# Java 7 and TLSv1.2 socket

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, prtg

I am trying to connect to a web server with encryption. The web server allows only connections using protocol TLSv1.2.

I've modified this snippet from [official doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/samples/sockets/client/SSLSocketClient.java)

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;

/*
 * This example demostrates how to use a SSLSocket as client to
 * send a HTTP request and get response from an HTTPS server.
 * It assumes that the client is not behind a firewall
 */

public class SSLSocketClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        String host = "172.20.172.106";
        SSLSocketFactory factory =
                (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, 443);
        String[] protocols = socket.getEnabledProtocols();
        System.out.println("Enabled Protocols: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < protocols.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(protocols[i] + ", ");
        }
        String[] supportedProtocols = socket.getSupportedProtocols();
        System.out.println("Supported Protocols: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < protocols.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(supportedProtocols[i] + ", ");
        }
        String[] goodProtocols = new String[1];
        goodProtocols[0] = "TLSv1.2";
        socket.setEnabledProtocols(goodProtocols);
        protocols = socket.getEnabledProtocols();
        System.out.println("Set Protocols: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < protocols.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(protocols[i] + ", ");
        }
        /*
         * send http request
         *
         * Before any application data is sent or received, the
         * SSL socket will do SSL handshaking first to set up
         * the security attributes.
         *
         * SSL handshaking can be initiated by either flushing data
         * down the pipe, or by starting the handshaking by hand.
         *
         * Handshaking is started manually in this example because
         * PrintWriter catches all IOExceptions (including
         * SSLExceptions), sets an internal error flag, and then
         * returns without rethrowing the exception.
         *
         * Unfortunately, this means any error messages are lost,
         * which caused lots of confusion for others using this
         * code.  The only way to tell there was an error is to call
         * PrintWriter.checkError().
         */
        socket.startHandshake();

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(
                                socket.getOutputStream())));

        out.println("GET / HTTP/1.0");
        out.println();
        out.flush();

        /*
         * Make sure there were no surprises
         */
        if (out.checkError())
            System.out.println(
                    "SSLSocketClient:  java.io.PrintWriter error");

        /* read response */
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);

        in.close();
        out.close();
        socket.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Now if I run this code with JRE 8 everything works fine.

This is the output I get

```
Enabled Protocols:
TLSv1,
TLSv1.1,
TLSv1.2,
Supported Protocols:
SSLv2Hello,
SSLv3,
TLSv1,
Set Protocols:
TLSv1.2,
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 09 Feb 2015 15:08:25 GMT
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: PRTG/15.1.13.1382
Location: /index.htm
```

But if I try with JRE1.7.0_75 with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` I get the following

```
Enabled Protocols:
TLSv1,
Supported Protocols:
SSLv2Hello,
Set Protocols:
TLSv1.2,

keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore

...SKIPPING CERTIFICATE INIT...

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Enabled Protocols: 
TLSv1, 
Supported Protocols: 
SSLv2Hello, 
Set Protocols: 
TLSv1.2, 
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1406651565 bytes = { 85, 112, 165, 115, 135, 15, 171, 1, 167, 182, 47, 68, 233, 53, 164, 111, 112, 244, 51, 252, 240, 40, 178, 238, 204, 215, 13, 137 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 179
0000: 01 00 00 AF 03 03 54 D8   CD AD 55 70 A5 73 87 0F  ......T...Up.s..
0010: AB 01 A7 B6 2F 44 E9 35   A4 6F 70 F4 33 FC F0 28  ..../D.5.op.3..(
0020: B2 EE CC D7 0D 89 00 00   2A C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0  ........*...../.
0030: 04 C0 0E 00 33 00 32 C0   08 C0 12 00 0A C0 03 C0  ....3.2.........
0040: 0D 00 16 00 13 C0 07 C0   11 00 05 C0 02 C0 0C 00  ................
0050: 04 00 FF 01 00 00 5C 00   0A 00 34 00 32 00 17 00  ......\...4.2...
0060: 01 00 03 00 13 00 15 00   06 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00  ................
0070: 18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00   0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00  ................
0080: 11 00 02 00 12 00 04 00   05 00 14 00 08 00 16 00  ................
0090: 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D 00   1A 00 18 06 03 06 01 05  ................
00A0: 03 05 01 04 03 04 01 03   03 03 01 02 03 02 01 02  ................
00B0: 02 01 01                                           ...
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 179
[Raw write]: length = 184
0000: 16 03 03 00 B3 01 00 00   AF 03 03 54 D8 CD AD 55  ...........T...U
0010: 70 A5 73 87 0F AB 01 A7   B6 2F 44 E9 35 A4 6F 70  p.s....../D.5.op
0020: F4 33 FC F0 28 B2 EE CC   D7 0D 89 00 00 2A C0 09  .3..(........*..
0030: C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E   00 33 00 32 C0 08 C0 12  .../.....3.2....
0040: 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00 16   00 13 C0 07 C0 11 00 05  ................
0050: C0 02 C0 0C 00 04 00 FF   01 00 00 5C 00 0A 00 34  ...........\...4
0060: 00 32 00 17 00 01 00 03   00 13 00 15 00 06 00 07  .2..............
0070: 00 09 00 0A 00 18 00 0B   00 0C 00 19 00 0D 00 0E  ................
0080: 00 0F 00 10 00 11 00 02   00 12 00 04 00 05 00 14  ................
0090: 00 08 00 16 00 0B 00 02   01 00 00 0D 00 1A 00 18  ................
00A0: 06 03 06 01 05 03 05 01   04 03 04 01 03 03 03 01  ................
00B0: 02 03 02 01 02 02 01 01                            ........
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at SSLSocketClient.main(SSLSocketClient.java:96)
```

jdk7 should support TLSv1.2, but I don't see it in supported protocols output

Comment: passing in `-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.1=true -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true` should enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 in java 7.

Comment: @Petesh Sounds like an answer Petesh

Comment: I've already tryed and doen't work

   `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java` `-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.1=true` `-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true SSLSocketClient`

`Enabled Protocols:`
`TLSv1,`
`Supported Protocols:`
`SSLv2Hello,`
`Set Protocols:`
`TLSv1.2,`
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert:` `handshake_failure`

Comment: The actual option, according to [a blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https) is `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2`, however the most likely reason for the handshake failure is that java 7 doesn't support any of the shared list of ciphers that the server offers, because, according to the log you posted, it's trying TLS1.2 (the `READ: TLSv1.2 Alert` messages seem to indicate this).

Comment: Also with `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` flag it doesn't work.

I don't think problem is  ciphers because in this case I excected to see an error message `no cipher suites in common` as mentioned in this  [post]()

Comment: [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076820/java-sslhandshakeexception-no-cipher-suites-in-common?rq=1)

Comment: Useless now but: your code didn't print out 'Supported Protocols' correctly because your second `for` loop uses `protocols.length` instead of `supportedProtocols.length`. Also, `deployment.security.*` only works for webstart/JNLP apps and applets (which browsers no longer support) and `https.protocols` only works for connections made by `URL.openConnection` not code using `SSLSocket[Factory]` directly as yours does.

Answer (score 9):

PRTG supports [4 ciphers](http://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/61108-what-security-features-does-prtg-include) with the high security mode set.

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

None of these are in the standard distribution of Java 1.7

However, in the [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7 Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) it does include `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA`

You need to download the unlimited strength zip and replace the `local_policy.jar` and `US_export_policy.jar` files in JRE_HOME/lib/security with the ones from the download.

**Edited 02/12/2016:**

You also need to enable the appropriate TLS version via the system property:

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

Comment: I did suggested solution but the same error is coming

Comment: As well as making sure ciphers match, you've also got to make sure that the certificate being used by your PRTG server is trusted by your java code.   If its an internal certificate etc, you might need to add the certificate to your trust store.

Comment: Yes, this fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 5):

Finally I've found the problem: the PRTG server I'm trying to connect when set in mode `SSL security: high security` seems to accept only secure connections using `TLSv1.2` and cipher `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`, that is available only on java 8.

@Petesh thank you for your support