# What I need to know how to implement the TSL (https)?

Tags: java, ssl, https

I made my implementation of the HTTP protocol following the specification of the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/) in Java. But I can't handle https connections.

Comment: The code you have posted is both irrelevant and wrong. You need to take a really good look at RFC [2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) and friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about HTTPs when it comes to HTTP protocol. All you need is to [open server SSL socket](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/CreatinganSSLServerSocket.htm) and once the new connection comes, get the socket's input stream and you can use it (maybe after wrapping to buffered input stream) in the same way as for HTTP.

```
int port = 443;
ServerSocketFactory ssocketFactory = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
ServerSocket ssocket = ssocketFactory.createServerSocket(port);

Socket socket = ssocket.accept();
```

**EDIT**: You might be missing server keystore. Pls try to follow this tutorial: http://stilius.net/java/java_ssl.php i.e.

1. generate server keystore:

   keytool -genkey -keystore mySrvKeystore -keyalg RSA
2. run your server with proper arguments like:

   java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=mySrvKeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=123456 EchoServer

Comment: I receive this exception:
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common`

Comment: answer updated. I guess this is exception from server (not the client)

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very helpful. It took only complete with the two links: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076820/java-sslhandshakeexception-no-cipher-suites-in-common](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076820/java-sslhandshakeexception-no-cipher-suites-in-common) and [http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/07/java-keystore-tutorial.html](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/07/java-keystore-tutorial.html)