# Java - SSL server creation

Tags: java, ssl, keytool

I'm not experienced at all using SSL. I created a very simple client server and can successfully both send and retrieve files from the server with my client. I generated a keystore with a self-signed X509 certificate via keytool command line and stored it in my server directory.

I'm a little confused though, since I initially created my server using http://stilius.net/java/java_ssl.php as a guide but couldn't get it to work, I was using

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", jksFilepath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", jkspass);
```

to link my keystore with the server. Whenever I tried to retrieve a file I would get Java SSLHandshakeException “no cipher suites in common”.

However when I now use code identical to: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/SSLContextandKeymanager.htm 
to setup my server, it works perfectly fine.

Also, the second guide just uses a ServerSocket and not an SSLSocket - which should I be using? Switching between both doesn't seem to change anything when I run the server and retrieve a file.

Comment: Check the second link. It is broken http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/SSLContextandKeymanager.htm

Comment: import the certificate in jre security..

Comment: Second example creates an `SSLServerSockst`, but stores it into a `ServerSocket` variable. Doesn't matter unless you need to call an `SSLServerSocket` method.

Answer (score 0):

Check this
[Java SSLHandshakeException "no cipher suites in common"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076820/java-sslhandshakeexception-no-cipher-suites-in-common) for a possible duplicate of your issue

In the second example link the `SSLContext and KeyManager` are inited. In the first example they are not. 
If you want your keystore to be used as a keystore, you'll need to load it and initialise a KeyManagerFactory with it:

This is the code of the second example. `SSLContext` is inited with `KeyManagers`

```
context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(storename);
ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ks.load(fin, storepass);
context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
```

In the first example is created a default SSLSocketFactory

```
SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
```

`SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()` invokes `SSLContext.getDefault()` which creates the default context (without the parameters you need)